# How to use an If/then condition on a Variant/double array value?

Tags: excel, vba, osisoft

I am trying to look at each value of the array generated by my function, and place it in a cell if the value is <> 0, but I always get a type mismatch error at that stage. The code will place a value inside the cells as it is written, but I want to scrub the 0 values from the set and replace with "-".

Vals0(1 to 30)

```
Do While (Now - 1) > fdate0
    looop0 = 1
    Start = DateAdd("n", 450, PT.Range("P2").Value)
    Endd = DateAdd("d", 1, Start)
    E0.Cells((counter0), 1).Value = fdate0

    For looop0 = 1 To 30

        vals0(looop0) = Application.Run("PIAdvCalcVal", E0Tags(looop0), Start, Endd, "average (time-weighted)", "time-weighted", "0", "1", "0")

       ' If Vals0(looop0) <> 0 Then
            E0.Cells(counter0, (looop0 + 1)).Value = vals0(looop0)
        'Else
         '   E0.Cells(counter0, (looop0 + 1)).Value = "-"
        'End If

    Next looop0


    counter0 = counter0 + 1
    PT.Range("P2").Value = (PT.Range("P2").Value + 1)
    fdate0 = PT.Range("P2").Value

Loop
```

[Here is the locals window for a few iterations of the for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOCqs.png)

Comment: You should probably post more code. Which line errors?

Comment: Which line has the error, and what does the error say?  Where have you defined `vals0`?  Is it 0-based or 1-based? (i.e. `vals0(0 to 99)` or `vals0(1 to 100)` - look up the `ubound` and `lbound` functions)  Is it 1-dimentional or more? (e.g. `vals0(1 to 100)``vals0(1 to 100, 1 to 2)`)

Comment: I have it commented out now, but "If Vals0(looop0) <> 0 Then" gives me a type mismatch error, it is Vals0(1 to 30)

Comment: What is `vals0(looop0)` at the moment where you get the runtime error? Strange naming convention you have, btw...

Comment: Its a double. like 18.747474382282 or something. 13 decimals I think. Naming convention necessary, I have a bunch of these structures 0 through 9 indicating equipment names.

Comment: When you find yourself appending a numerical suffix to a variable to separate it from others of the same type but similar function, it's usually a sign that you should be using arrays or some other structure.

Comment: A double wouldn't throw an type mismatch. Must be something different.

Comment: probably, Ive only been coding for a month so I don't know the "right" way to do anything.

Comment: @FunThomas It Says Variant/Double, then when I go into the array in the local window, the double value is listed as vals0(1)(1) =18.2738746824382 and it is placed into the cell in the same way, as you can see in the code above. it just errors when I try to compare it to 0

Comment: If the local window is showing two indices for values in `vals0`, then that means that `vals0` is a 2-dimensional array, and the comparison to zero is being done with an array, not a number.

Comment: When I use Vals0(looops0,1), the debug says that Vals0 is a single dimensional array. It is also declared as a single dimensional array. Regardless, How can I get the array value to compare to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote *"It Says Variant/Double, then when I go into the array in the local window, the double value is listed as vals0(1)(1) =18.2738746824382"*. So, obviously `vals0(1)` is not a double, it is an array of double.

Unfortunately you don't tell us anything about `PIAdvCalcVal`. `vals0` is declared as (one-dimensional) array with 30(?) element of type `Variant`. That means you have 30 variants. Every variant can hold *anything*, a double, a string, an object, or also an *Array* of anything. The latter seems to be the case, `PIAdvCalcVal` returned an array of double values (even if the array holds maybe only one value).

So first things first: Put a statement `Debug.Print looop0, VarType(vals0(looop0))` after your `Run`-statement. Have a look to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function to get an idea about the numbers representing a vartype. If the vartype is something > 8192, you have an array of something, and that would explain the *Type mismatch* error - you cannot compare an array with a number.

If `PIAdvCalcVal` always returns an array, the solution could be to simply write `If Vals0(looop0)(1) <> 0` (note that `Vals0(looop0, 1)` will not work as `Vals0` is not a 2-dimensional array).

A more robust solution could be

```
Var x
If IsArray(Vals0(looop0)) Then
    x = Vals0(looop0)(1)
Else
    x = Vals0(looop0)
End If
If x <> 0 Then
...
```

Finally, you have to check how large the returned array is (check `LBound` and `UBound`). What would you do if it contains more than one value?

Comment: Thanks, I am really new at this so I apologize for my incorrect use of terminology. I appreciate you helping me solve this issue. The piadvcalcval is a black box situation so I don't know that it will always be an array.